# How to listen to URL routes in perl

Tags: perl

I'm starting my first perl project, and wanted to know how to listen to different end points, I.e. `example.com/home` (how do you load an HTML page when someone visits this home route?

Just a note that I'm not interested in using a framework for this particular project. Thanks

Comment: For such question you *have* to specify your environment. Which web server are you using? (Apache/IIS/etc) then people may be able to give server-level solution. 
If the project uses a framework, it is possible to make a framework-level solution. but we need something to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess you could have a CGI program that interprets the path and takes the appropriate action. You could then combine that with a mod_rewrite rule that diverts all requests into that program.

But it's all looking a bit kludgy and a framework would be a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to talk to a server is [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). 
This is not Perl specific, but Perl was commonly used for it.  It is very slow, but simple.

Here is small demo.  You put this in the cgi-bin directory of your server, and go go http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/cgidemo.cgi and back pops the content of the Perl @INC array.

To hook it up to /home you could alias it in your .htaccess file.

Of course, this is all ancient and slow stuff and has been far surpassed and sped up by fastcgi, mod_perl, and lots of other stuff.  I like the Mojolicous framework myself.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#  cgidemo.cgi - minimal CGI program

use strict;
use warnings;

# Headers
print "Content-type: text/plain\n";

# Blank line after header
print "\n";

# Body
print "Perl Include Path:\n";
print join("\n", @INC), "\n";
```

Comment: thanks for the input. i'm thinking about using LWP::Simple and listening to urls like that, and then based on those routes loading template toolkit pages, performing whatever queries are needed and passing them to that view. that will act as a front controller.

Comment: I'm not at all sure why you think LWP::Simple will be useful - that's for writing an HTTP client, not an HTTP server application.

Comment: Sorry, after a bit more investigation I believe CGI is what I'm after. That way I can do CGI->new->url() and respond with different content.